# Android auto backup error

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I'm trying to implement android auto backup (Android 6.0) but it doesn't work.

I get the same error with

```
10-28 22:58:06.980 600-5578/? I/PFTBT: Initiating full-data transport backup of com.myapp.package
10-28 22:58:06.981 7891-14015/? I/GmsBackupTransport: Attempt to do full backup on com.myapp.package
10-28 22:58:06.982 600-5578/? I/PFTBT: Transport rejected backup of com.myapp.package, skipping
10-28 22:58:06.982 600-5578/? I/PFTBT: Full backup completed.
10-28 22:58:06.982 600-610/? D/BackupManagerService: Done with full transport backup.
```

I tried enable

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.BackupXmlParserLogging VERBOSE
```

and

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GmsBackupTransport VERBOSE
```

but I don't see any more information in the logcat. After turning backup off and on I instead get this error. How to resolve it?

```
10-28 23:53:08.699  1633  1644 I GmsBackupTransport: Attempt to do full backup on com.myapp.package
10-28 23:53:08.699  1633  1644 V GmsBackupTransport: Rejecting full data backup. user has not seen up to date legal text
10-28 23:53:08.699   599  8353 I PFTBT   : Transport rejected backup of com.myapp.package, skipping
10-28 23:53:08.699   599  8353 I PFTBT   : Full backup completed.
10-28 23:53:08.699   599  6518 D BackupManagerService: Done with full transport backup.
```

I've followed the guide here [Auto backup](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the legal text.

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) :

> Note: To protect user privacy, the device user must have opted in to
>   Google services for Auto Backup to work. The Google services opt-in
>   dialog appears when the user goes through the Setup Wizard or
>   configures the first Google account on the device.

The problem was that I never saw this dialog. 
So I cleared all the data of Google play services, disabled it, enabled it again and opened the Play Store app. I had to add my account and at the end of the process, the dialog appeared.

Then, don't forget to update Google Play Services to the last version else you won't have a backup account assigned. At the end of the update, you should be able to execute the command `adb shell bmgr fullbackup <PACKAGE>` properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to uninstall updates to Google Play Services (since I could not fully uninstall it) and then after uninstallation I got a message to select account for backup. Then I installed latest version and tried to make a backup. But then I'm back to this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456266/android-6-0-app-backup-error with the legal text.  And if I try another account I get the error "Try to backup for an uninitialized backup account.". I'll continue testing..

Comment: I updated my answer, I forgot to mention that right after disabling/enabling Google play services, I opened the Play store.

Comment: I never succeeded, so I gave up and factory resetted the tablet instead to make it work..

Comment: @Esteam When you cleared data/disabled/enabled Google Play Services, did you lose any app data or need to re-install anything?