# Android 6.0 app backup error

Tags: android, android-backup-service

When I try to backup with auto backup I only get this error message in logcat. How to solve it? I don't find anywhere to see the legal text.. :/

```
Attempt to do full backup on <mypackage>
[ 10-31 21:17:30.360  1633: 1678 V/GmsBackupTransport ]
Rejecting full data backup. user has not seen up to date legal text
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can find how I managed to fix this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33478196/1176435