# Android 6 - fullBackupContent issue

Tags: android, backup

I'm developping an app with `targetSdkVersion 23`.
I would like to use auto-backup service from Google, but it does not work.
I'm using example found on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html)

I have configured my `AndroidManifest.xml` with

```
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/akbackupscheme"
```

and `akbackupscheme.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="mysharedpref"/>
    <include domain="database" path="mydatabase.db"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

I'm using adb to test it and these are traces I got :

> ./adb shell bmgr fullbackup com.*****
>
> Performing full transport backup
>
> ./adb shell bmgr restore com.*****
>
> Unable to restore package com.*****
>
> done

Here are some traces :

> 11-25 17:05:47.977 1419-1419/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry
> com.android.commands.bmgr.Bmgr
>
> 11-25 17:05:47.982 603-1101/? W/BackupManagerService: Requested
> unavailable transport:
> com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
>
> 11-25 17:05:47.982 603-1101/? W/BackupManagerService: Transport not
> present; full data backup not performed
>
> 11-25 17:05:47.982 603-1101/? I/BackupManagerService: Full backup not
> currently possible -- key/value backup not yet run?
>
> 11-25 17:05:47.982 603-1101/? D/BackupManagerService: Done with full
> transport backup.

Comment: You aren't alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743941/how-do-you-test-the-android-6-0-full-backup-behavior

Comment: I just added in Android preference a gmail account and now i get that : 11-25 18:15:21.858 1490-1516/? I/GmsBackupTransport: Attempt to do full backup on com.*****
11-25 18:15:21.859 1490-1516/? V/GmsBackupTransport: Rejecting full data backup. user has not seen up to date legal text

Comment: Yeah, that's a messy problem. I found a solution here on Stack Overflow somewhere (search on "user has not seen up to date legal text"). IIRC, I wound up having to remove my Google account from the device, re-apply it, and then do something else (toggle on and off backups?) to get this "legal text" to appear and get past this message.

Comment: @CommonsWare When you removed your Google Account from the device, did you lose data from apps or have to re-install anything? What process did you use to remove your Account?

Comment: "When you removed your Google Account from the device, did you lose data from apps or have to re-install anything?" -- well, it was a test device, so I don't know what I would have lost. I would expect that, at most, it might have affected some of Google's apps. "What process did you use to remove your Account?" -- IIRC, I just removed it via Settings > Accounts > Google > "Remove account".

Comment: This did fix my issue, and my app is now being backed up apparently. My test device is also my personal device, so removing the account was a little scary, but I have a NAndroid backup so...anyway, I cleared Google Play Services, removed my Google Account as above, added it back in, had a few panic moments, rebooted and now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: I get a 'PFTBT: Transport rejected backup' :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  Removing and then re-adding my Google account resolved it.  I selected 'back up this device to google drive' when adding the account back but I'm not sure if that actually had any effect.

Once the account was added back I noticed a lot of backup-related logcat spam and the next time I requested a full backup it worked.

```
D/BackupManagerService: fullTransportBackup()
I/PFTBT: Requested package com.example.mh.backuptest not found; ignoring
I/PFTBT: Full backup completed with status: 0
I/BackupManagerService: Full data backup pass finished.
D/BackupManagerService: Done with full transport backup.
```