# Android SharedPreferencesBackupHelper fails to restore data on pre-Android 6 devices

Tags: android, backup, android-backup-service

I'm trying to get my app to auto-backup and restore its shared preferences as per the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html). Both backup and restore work fine on an Android 6.0 device. However, although the backup works on pre-Android 6 devices, the *restore* fails. The precise error messages I see in logcat depend on the device being tested. Examples:

### Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, Android 4.1.2

```
07-02 11:05:00.240 2013-24968/? V/BackupManagerService: beginRestoreSession: pkg=com.my.app transport=null
07-02 11:05:00.260 2013-2024/? V/RestoreSession: restorePackage pkg=com.my.app obs=android.app.backup.IRestoreObserver$Stub$Proxy@42364000
07-02 11:05:00.260 2013-2119/? D/BackupManagerService: MSG_RUN_RESTORE observer=android.app.backup.IRestoreObserver$Stub$Proxy@42364000
07-02 11:05:01.340 2013-2119/? D/BackupManagerService: initiateOneRestore packageName=@pm@
07-02 11:05:01.420 2013-2119/? V/BackupServiceBinder: doRestore() invoked
07-02 11:05:01.500 2013-2119/? V/BackupManagerService: Package com.my.app restore version [24] is compatible with installed version [24]
07-02 11:05:01.530 2013-2119/? D/BackupManagerService: awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{4240d338 com.my.app}
07-02 11:05:01.651 2013-2022/? D/BackupManagerService: agentConnected pkg=com.my.app agent=android.os.BinderProxy@424b9d48
07-02 11:05:01.651 2013-2119/? I/BackupManagerService: got agent android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub$Proxy@4274be90
07-02 11:05:01.651 2013-2119/? D/BackupManagerService: initiateOneRestore packageName=com.my.app
07-02 11:05:01.661 14846-14857/? V/BackupServiceBinder: doRestore() invoked
07-02 11:05:01.661 14846-14857/? W/BackupHelperDispatcher: Couldn't find helper for: 'prefs:VirtualSavingsPrefs'
07-02 11:05:01.661 14846-14857/? D/backup_data: Chunk header at 40 has invalid type: 0x6144bcbc
07-02 11:05:01.661 14846-14857/? D/BackupServiceBinder: onRestore (com.my.app.PreferencesBackupAgent) threw
                                                        java.io.IOException: failed: 0xffffffff
                                                            at android.app.backup.BackupDataInput.readNextHeader(BackupDataInput.java:112)
                                                            at android.app.backup.BackupHelperDispatcher.performRestore(BackupHelperDispatcher.java:111)
                                                            at android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper.onRestore(BackupAgentHelper.java:75)
                                                            at android.app.backup.BackupAgent$BackupServiceBinder.doRestore(BackupAgent.java:527)
                                                            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:106)
                                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-02 11:05:01.751 2013-2119/? V/BackupManagerService: No next package, finishing restore
```

### Samsung Galaxy A3, Android 5.0.2

```
07-02 14:44:21.159 1002-1355/? V/BackupManagerService: beginRestoreSession: pkg=com.my.app transport=null
07-02 14:44:21.159 1002-4292/? V/RestoreSession: restorePackage pkg=com.my.app obs=android.app.backup.IRestoreObserver$Stub$Proxy@345efd33
07-02 14:44:21.159 1002-1128/? D/BackupManagerService: MSG_RUN_RESTORE observer=android.app.backup.IRestoreObserver$Stub$Proxy@345efd33
07-02 14:44:21.589 1529-1538/? I/GmsBackupTransport: Http Response Code : 200
07-02 14:44:21.619 1529-1872/? I/GmsBackupTransport: Current restore package : PackageInfo{207b91f @pm@}
07-02 14:44:21.619 1002-1128/? D/BackupManagerService: initiateOneRestore packageName=@pm@
07-02 14:44:21.649 1002-1128/? V/BackupServiceBinder: doRestore() invoked
07-02 14:44:21.659 1529-1871/? I/GmsBackupTransport: Current restore package : PackageInfo{4ab746c com.my.app}
07-02 14:44:21.659 1002-1128/? I/BackupManagerService: Next restore package: RestoreDescription{com.my.app : KEY_VALUE}
07-02 14:44:21.659 1002-1128/? V/BackupManagerService: Package com.my.app restore version [24] is compatible with installed version [24]
07-02 14:44:21.659 1002-1128/? D/BackupManagerService: awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{2638d65b com.my.app}
07-02 14:44:21.659 1002-1014/? D/BackupManagerService: agentConnected pkg=com.my.app agent=android.os.BinderProxy@1551c6dd
07-02 14:44:21.659 1002-1128/? I/BackupManagerService: got agent android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub$Proxy@2a573252
07-02 14:44:21.659 1002-1128/? D/BackupManagerService: initiateOneRestore packageName=com.my.app
07-02 14:44:21.669 1002-1128/? E/BackupManagerService: SElinux restorecon failed for /cache/com.my.app.stage
07-02 14:44:21.669 17200-17214/? V/BackupServiceBinder: doRestore() invoked
07-02 14:44:21.669 17200-17214/? D/backup_data: SKIP_PADDING FAILED at line 334
07-02 14:44:21.669 1002-1128/? V/BackupManagerService: No more packages; finishing restore
07-02 14:44:21.699 1002-1128/? I/BackupRestoreController: restoreFinished for 0
07-02 14:44:21.699 1002-1128/? I/BackupManagerService: Restore complete.
07-02 14:44:21.699 1002-1128/? E/RestoreSession: Error in finishRestore
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.Set evs.d' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
                                                     at com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub$Proxy.finishRestore(IBackupTransport.java:819)
                                                     at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$ActiveRestoreSession$EndRestoreRunnable.run(BackupManagerService.java:9477)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-02 14:44:21.699 1002-1128/? V/BackupManagerService: Clearing restore session and halting timeout
```

The log messages tagged with `backup_data` suggest some error occurs when trying to read in the backup data. **Has anyone seen and know how to fix errors like this?** I haven't been able to debug into the backup code to see what's going wrong.

I know the backup works because I can see a correctly timestamped backup entry for my app under each tested device under the Android section of https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard.

To support pre-Android 6 devices I extended `BackupAgentHelper` and added a `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper` in its `onCreate()` method as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/backupapi.html#agent). The one thing different from the docs is that I had to precede the name of my backup agent helper class with a '.' in my manifest to avoid a class-not-found exception when loading the app. i.e.,:

```
android:backupAgent=".PreferencesBackupAgent"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743941/how-do-you-test-the-android-6-0-full-backup-behavior   lots of good links in thread

Comment: Thanks. That is a useful link but my problems are with restoring on pre-Android 6 devices. Backup and restore works fine for me on Android 6.0. And I'm seeing different errors to the ones they reported. However it does give me the idea to try and look inside the backup file itself to see if and where it might be corrupted...

Comment: "Support lower versions of android" https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html pointed to by earluer link

Comment: Thanks; yeah; I've done all of that. It just doesn't work for me as you can see from the error messages.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @Ogix. No I haven't I'm afraid. I put it aside to concentrate on other things but I would still like to fix it and will look at it again. If you find a fix post it here please. My thoughts were to look inside the backup file to see which preference(s) might be causing the problem; and also to write a simple test app which tries to back-up and restore one preference. If that fails on a pre-Android 6 device then I could raise a bug against Google/Android with the test case. There may already be a bug raised for all I know...