# Android auto backup not working: Transport rejected package because it wasn't able to process it at the time

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, backup, auto

I have developed an application with Flutter and Sqlite and I can't get the android auto backup working.
I have explicitly put android:allowBackup="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml. 
The very first time I executed the command:

adb shell bmgr backupnow

I got:

> Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages. Package @pm@ with
>   result: Success Package  with result: Size quota
>   exceeded Backup finished with result: Success

After that time I got:

> Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages. Package @pm@ with
>   result: Success Package  with result: Transport rejected
>   package because it wasn't able to process it at the time Backup
>   finished with result: Success

I can't understand why I have the error "Size quota exceeded": the sqlite database size is far below 25 mb! I have tried on different devices, with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding being over 25MB, are there any flutter temporary files used to speed up debugging installed in the app's private folders?
If you have a debuggable app installed, you should be able to query the internal storage of the app to see what's stored there by calling:

```
adb shell run-as <APP_PACKAGENAME> ls -al
```

That way you can see what is in the files and databases folders it's trying to backup.  If there are files you want to exclude, or only a few you want to include in the backup you can specify custom rules by adding:

```
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
```

along side the android:allowBackup="true" setting (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup for more details on the contents of that xml file).

It might also be worth logging into Google Backups to see the backups associated with the Google account you're logged in with.  From there you can see how many apps, and how much setting data is stored, and delete stale backups.

You may also delete a device's backup by toggling off and on again the Backup To Google Drive setting.  That way you'd know you're starting a test from "fresh".

After trying various combinations of backup commands from other "solutions" I found MH's answer here: [How Do You Test the Android 6.0 Full-Backup Behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743941/how-do-you-test-the-android-6-0-full-backup-behavior)

By deleting the test device's backup, then following the steps in that link that got me past the Quota and "Transport rejected package because it wasn't able to process it at the time" errors I was seeing, and get an actual backup response like:

```
Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
  Package @pm@ with result: Success
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 512/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 2560/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 10752/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 18944/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 27136/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 35328/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 43520/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 51712/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 59904/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 68096/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with progress: 68608/66048
  Package com.example.myapp with result: Success
  Backup finished with result: Success
```

After that, uninstalling and re-installing the app on that test device showed the backed up content correctly restored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing a flutter app and ran into the same problem, and followed [google's instructions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles) on how to customize the backup manager to fix it.

It turns out that flutter's build for android creates a directory structure with (for me) 56M of disk usage, which is beyond the 25MB limit.

The fix is to add a `backup_rules.xml` file to your `android/app/src/main/res/xml/` directory (create it if it doesn't exist), which tells the backup manager to *exclude* the `flutter_app/` directory.

Here's the steps for getting this resolved:

1. First, look at the space used using `adb` and the "du" command:

```
% adb shell run-as com.example.yourapp_namehere du -h
3.5K    ./cache
3.5K    ./code_cache/flutter_engine/04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed/skia/e2621f417ff57ccab752a59bd8c938ade1bb9b4c/sksl
159K    ./code_cache/flutter_engine/04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed/skia/e2621f417ff57ccab752a59bd8c938ade1bb9b4c
163K    ./code_cache/flutter_engine/04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed/skia
166K    ./code_cache/flutter_engine/04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed
170K    ./code_cache/flutter_engine
3.5K    ./code_cache/yourapp_namehereILJTYZ/yourapp_namehere
7.0K    ./code_cache/yourapp_namehereILJTYZ
180K    ./code_cache
56M ./app_flutter/flutter_assets
56M ./app_flutter
3.5K    ./files
12K ./shared_prefs
56M .
```

2. Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` to add the exclusion rule file within the `<application` tag's list, near the top most likely, so it has this:

```
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
```

3. Create the file `./android/app/src/main/res/xml/backup_rules.xml` (you may have to create the `xml/` directory inside `res/` if it doesn't already exist.  Within this file, include the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
  <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
  <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="app_flutter/"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

4. Rebuild your app and re-deploy it to your mobile device/phone, so it has the updated android manifest and backup_rules files locally.  Don't forget this step.
5. Give it a shot using google's suggested `test_cloud_backup.sh` script, given on [their docs site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup#TestingBackup).  I had no trouble with my app after I made these changes.

So, what's in that "flutter_app/flutter_assets/" directory?  I'm not entirely sure of the details, but it looks like the flutter runtime's binaries, based on the filenames:

```
% adb shell run-as com.tenthlight.evaporative_cooler ls -lh app_flutter/flutter_assets/
./app_flutter/flutter_assets:
total 56M
-rw------- 1 u0_a283 u0_a283 10M 2024-03-19 12:03 isolate_snapshot_data
-rw------- 1 u0_a283 u0_a283 46M 2024-03-19 12:03 kernel_blob.bin
-rw------- 1 u0_a283 u0_a283 12K 2024-03-19 12:03 vm_snapshot_data
```

So, it was the kernel_blob and the isolate_snapshot_data files that were the problem.  There's no need to back up those files.